# How to combine {a,z} and {1..3} to produce a z 1 2 3 output in bash

Tags: bash

I have recently run into a case where I wanted to list something similar to a z 1 2 3 used in a file name generation, so I could get `file_a.txt` ... `file_3.txt`
Se below:

```
# echo file_{a,z}.txt
file_a.txt file_z.txt
# echo file_{1..3}.txt
file_1.txt file_2.txt file_3.txt
# echo file_{a,z,1..3}.txt
file_a.txt file_z.txt file_1..3.txt
```

As you can see combining both will display something else than I would expect.

How can I write this range expression to generate `a z 1 2 3`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can nest one expression in another:

```
$ echo file_{a,z,{1..3}}.txt
file_a.txt file_z.txt file_1.txt file_2.txt file_3.txt
```